# Photoshop: Trouble copying and pasting layers to another file

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would have two layers selected from "Regular Rects.psd", hit CMD + C, and click on the canvas for the destination psd file. When I paste it, it shows the two rectangles in the destination PSD file but the layers are not appearing in the layers panel. Could you someone explain to me the proper way to copy and paste layers to different files in Photoshop?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should be able to select the layers and copy + paste into a new document. You can also drag them from one file to another. So after you copied the 2 layers in the new document, the 2 shape layers turned into 1 layer and the layer name changed?

Comment: The 2 rectangles turned into a combined shape but didn't appear at all in the layer panel.

Comment: Try RMB on your shape layers (in Layers panel) and select 'duplicate layers', then select target document. I believe you're copy-pasting path data, not layers themselves

Comment: Just drag the highlighted layers to the tab of the other document - it'll bounce forward... drop. You don't *really* need to copy/paste.

Comment: I didn't even know this feature had been added... It looks like your PS version is high enough that it should work since I can do it in CC 2019, but yea, it has not always been possible to copy layers into another document by `cmd+c` and then `cmd+v` in another document.